# Structure, pointer and casting core dump

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, casting

I have a C program written 30 years ago (for ISAM files) that has a section in it that I could use some help understanding / fixing. The person that wrote this saw there could be future issues by his / her comments. It compiles fine but core dumps.

Here is the problem line:

```
altkptr = (struct keydat *)(++header);
```

Code in function:

```
 struct  indxheader {
    int     pnumrecs ;
    long    pnxtposn ;
    int     pnextnode ;
    long    pfreedat ;
    int     pfreenodes;
#ifdef  FIXED_RECLEN
    int preclength;     /* Added 23-Jun-89 .. kavi */
#endif
    int paltkeys ;
};

struct  keydat {
    int     pkeylength,
        proot,
        pmaxkeys,
        pnodesize,
        pnumkeys,
        pkeyparts ,
        *partsarray ;
};


static  int buildtables(alloc_flg) 
int alloc_flg ;     /* if occupy slot etc are to be called */
{
struct  indxheader  *header ;
struct  keydat      *altkptr;

int savekey, i ;
int *sptr, *dptr ;

    savekey = currkeyno ;

    if(seek(0) == ERROR) 
        reterr(NODSKERR);
    if(read(currslot.fd2,ptr2,INXHSZ)<INXHSZ)
        reterr(IFLRDERR); /* SIZE OF HEADER BLOCK IN FILE < SIZE DECLARED IN ISNAMES.H */

    header = (struct indxheader *)ptr2 ;
    currslot.numrecords = header->pnumrecs ; /*added .. if i have luck*/
#ifdef  FIXED_RECLEN
    currslot.reclength =  header->preclength ;
#endif

    currslot.nxtposn = header->pnxtposn;
    currslot.nextnode = header->pnextnode;
    currslot.freedat = header->pfreedat;
    currslot.freenodes = header->pfreenodes;
    currslot.altkeys = header->paltkeys;

/** If occupyslot to be called then check **/

    if ( alloc_flg )
        if (alloctable() == ERROR) return (ERROR) ;
    altkptr = (struct keydat *)(++header); /* deserves attention..*/

    for(currkeyno = 0;currkeyno<currslot.altkeys;currkeyno++) {
        currindex.proot = altkptr->proot;
        if (currindex.proot == -1) reterr (CRPIXFLERR) ;
        currindex.pmaxkeys = altkptr->pmaxkeys;
        currindex.pnodesize = altkptr->pnodesize;
        currindex.pnumkeys = altkptr->pnumkeys;
        currindex.pkeyparts = altkptr->pkeyparts ;
        currindex.pkeylength = altkptr->pkeylength ;
        altkptr++ ;
        sptr = (int *)altkptr ;
        if (alloc_flg) {
            if ((currindex.partsarray = dptr = (int *)malloc((unsigned)(currindex.pkeyparts*4)*sizeof(int))) == NULL) reterr(MEMORYERR) ;
            for (i = 0 ; i<(currindex.pkeyparts*4) ; i++)
                *dptr++ = *sptr++ ;
        }
        else sptr += (currindex.pkeyparts*4) ;
        altkptr = (struct keydat *)sptr ;
    }
    currkeyno = savekey ;   /*restore currkeyno to its initial value*/
    return (NOERROR);
}
```

Comment: When it coredumps, what is the error message? Inspect the core dump with your favorite debugger, it will tell you more. But I don't see how `altkptr = (struct keydat *)(++header)` could cause a problem, as it is a simple pointer assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`header` is a pointer to `struct indxheader`

It is being cast to `altkptr` which is a `struct keydat`

This is:

```
altkptr = (struct keydat *)(++header);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
++header;
altkptr = (struct keydat *) header;
```

Whether the casting was valid or not back in 1989 may be a debate point. But ...

The increment of `header` is the issue.

In 1989, a `long` had the same `sizeof` [and therefore alignment in the `struct`] as an `int`. This was because most/all CPUs were 32 bit (or 16 bit).

Now, you're probably on a 64 bit machine. So, `long` is 64 bits.

So, in 1989, size of each `struct` [probably] matched up. Now, the sizes are [probably] different

So, the increment of `header` isn't valid.

You *might* have luck compiling with `-m32` for force 32 bit mode compilation.  But, this code is so rickety otherwise that I'd say use it as a [loose] guide and rewrite what you can.

---

**UPDATE:**

I've been writing C code since 1981, so I'm somewhat familiar with the systems that were available then.

One of the issues is that the `keydat` struct has an embedded pointer that is being stored to and read back from the ISAM file.

If this is so, dereferencing such a read back pointer will almost certainly segfault or produce incorrect results.

That's because there's no guaranteed that the program has loaded into memory in the same place.

A key question is if you're trying to port this code so you can read existing old ISAM files that were created long ago. If not, it would be best to use the existing code as a guide, and rewrite from scratch.

If you *do* have to read old files, it would help to know exactly the type of system the software was being run on.

If it was run on a PC of that era under MS/DOS, an `int` was probably 16 bits and a `long` was 32 bits.

If it was run on a Motorola `mc68000` Unix system (e.g. old Sun Microsystems) [I was in a startup company that designed and manufactured a similar system], a `long` was 32 bits, but an `int` could be 16 bits or 32 bits. Most systems used 32 bits for `int`, but, it was the choice of the compiler.

Also, PCs are/were little endian, but the `mc68000` Unix systems were big endian.

So, first, you have to determine the `sizeof` for `int`, `long`, and a pointer for the system from the era.

Also, you need to determine what alignment of struct members was used.

Then, you may have to rewrite the function that reads in that data, almost byte-for-byte and do a conversion on a per-field basis the get the correct number of bytes to read for the field and its endianness.

This is similar to what `XDR` has to do.

Comment: Sounds good, but why should it crash at the assignment? There is no dereferencement whatsoever and incrementing `header` is not wrong in itself. But casting from one of the struct to the other one looks pretty fishy anyway..

Comment: @Jabberwocky We may have to read the fine print ... [in OP's question]. He said that it was the "problem line". A fine point, but that didn't say that the segfault happened there. As you said, it _can't_ segfault as it's just an increment, not a deref. So, my take on this is that OP [as he mentioned] is basing this off the comment on the line. The segfault probably occurs later.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense - appreciate it.  On a side note it was run  on an old NCR 3000 that had micro-channel architecture on AT&T SVr4.  I do plan on rewriting anyway just working though the base to understand what was going on.  Thanks again for your time.